# List of keys that should most probably be removed from log files?

Tags: security, logging

Recently I noticed some sensitive data was being written out to a log file in an app I'm working on. I looked into it, and our app has a list of keys that it will remove from our logs before writing them out, but the list feels to me like it could be expanded.

**Is there a list somewhere of common keys that should be removed from log files when found?**

For example the following keys and their variations should probably never be logged anywhere in a log file

```
access_token
auth_token
client_id
client_secret
oauthSecret
oauthToken
password
refresh_token
connection_string
```

Note that I've seen the [OWASP Logging cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Logging_Cheat_Sheet), but it didn't seem to have any specifics in it, just generalizations.

Comment: Very good list. At our company, we mask out (with random number of `*`) everything that contains `password`, `secret` and `token`

Comment: yeah that's a good point.... we're doing regex's around the above values, but simplifying this to be keys that contains substrings of those values is probably best. One thing that came up when discussing this with people is that we were targeting values, like `X  = 1`, and `X:1` and it's quoted variants, but we weren't targettng XML values, like `<x>1</x>`, for what it's worth.

Comment: Hm, AFAIK, we do not have anything for values and quoted variants but we do watch for XML nodes, as those contain lot of juicy configuration data (e.g. connection tokens). During the XML node serialization step, we look for very specific tags and mask the content out.

Comment: If you have un-redacted logs that you want to send to a third party, you can use Sublime Text to retrospectively redact them - see  https://codingrob.medium.com/how-to-redact-text-from-hundreds-of-text-files-in-less-than-60-seconds-511b4b91c2d8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the best I've been able to come up with is the following, and I found my best results by searching for "redact secret password token" in Google.

#### Redact keys that have the following anywhere in their name

- remembering that keys can show up in any of the following ways: `x=y, x:y, 'x':y, "x":y <x>y</x>`
- token
- secret
- password
- session
- connection
- jwt

#### consider removing all username variations as well, like:

- username
- user_name
- user
- email
- credential

#### Redact values that look like

- credit card numbers
- social insurance numbers
- possibly email addresses

#### [Cloudera has a page](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/sg_redaction.html) detailing regular expressions for redacting some data values, not keys:

> Credit Card numbers (with separator)
>   \d{4}[^\w]\d{4}[^\w]\d{4}[^\w]\d{4}
>
> Social Security numbers (with separator)   \d{3}[^\w]\d{2}[^\w]\d{4}
>
> Email addresses    \b([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-._] \
>   *[A-Za-z0-9])@(([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z] \ [A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9]).)+([A-Za-z0-9] \
>   |[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])\b
>
> Hostnames  \b(([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-] \
>   *[A-Za-z0-9]).)+([A-Za-z0-9] \ |[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])\b

#### Node module for redacting data

https://github.com/watson/redact-secrets

Note: A coworker of mine did a great job of supplying me with a java sample of key value redacting in Java, using a regex to eliminate key values that contain `session,secret,token,password,passwd,connection' in xml and json, and quoted variants.

```
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Redact {
  private static final String prefix = "[\"']?(session|(auth_)?token|password|passwd|secret|connection)[\"']?";
  private static final String capture = "([\"']?)([\\w\\d!#$%()*+,-./:<=>?@[\\\\]^_`{|}~]+)([\"']?)";
  private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(prefix + "\\s*(=|:)\\s*" + capture, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

  public static String encryptSensitiveInfo(String message) {
    try {
      if (message == null) 
        return message;

      StringBuffer newStr = new StringBuffer(message);
      int lenDiff = 0;
      Matcher m = pattern.matcher(message);

      // Loop over message until all sensitive data is redacted
      while (m.find()) {
        String keyAndValue = m.group(0);
        String value = m.group(5);
        String REDACTED = "REDACTED";
        String replacementText = keyAndValue.replace(value, REDACTED);

        // Replace the key/value in the message with the new redacted
        // value, adjusting for where it is in the redacted version of
        // the input
        newStr = newStr.replace(m.start() - lenDiff, m.end() - lenDiff, replacementText);
        lenDiff += keyAndValue.length() - replacementText.length();
      }
      return newStr.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return message;
    }
  }
}
```